# ¿Cómo notifico a mi aplicación si hubo un cambio en una tabla de mi base de datos SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-forms

Me gustaría saber cómo puedo realizar esto ya que podría implementar un mecanismo de cache para una aplicación de ejemplo escrita en *C#*. Esta implementación está destinada a que termine como librería.

Sé que **EntityFramework** tiene un mecanismo algo parecido con *Auto Refresh* y que **NHibernate** tiene niveles de cache. Pero tengo una idea vaga del concepto y no tengo idea de cómo funcionan internamente.

Por lo poco que investigué, sé que algo tiene que ver con **SQL Server Broker Service**, donde el servicio envía mensajes a **MSMQ** y desde mi aplicación hago *pooling* contra **MSMQ** pero nunca vi un ejemplo de implementación.

### Actualización

Bien, para contextualizar a dónde se aplica esto, se trata de un *Sistema de Gestión de Almacenes a nivel industrial*. El sistema tiene alrededor de 15 servicios corriendo al mismo tiempo y preguntándole a la base de datos todo el tiempo sobre el movimiento de los productos y contenedores que están las respectivas zonas de almacenamiento.

### ¿Por qué razón hay 15 servicios funcionando?

El almacén que usa este sistema de gestión tiene varias líneas con escáneres de código de barra leyendo alrededor de 10 etiquetas por minuto en hora pico y, cada una de esta líneas, tiene un servicio en particular porque varía la lógica en cada línea y en cada lógica hace una verificación a diferentes servicios y la existencia de dicho código de barras en la base de datos.

Además, tiene 10 *AGV (Automated Guided Vehicle)* que tienen servicios como: *Emisor de tareas para AGV*, *Planificador de Tareas a realizar*, etc. y estos están constantemente *pooleando* contra la base de datos buscando nuevas tareas para realizar. Lo mismo sucede con las terminales de los operarios de montacargas que todo el tiempo *poolean* la base de datos en busca de nuevas órdenes de movimiento de contenedores.

Falta agregar que también la recepción, despacho y almacenado también están automatizados y cada uno de estos tiene su(s) propio(s) servicio(s).

### ¿Por qué el sistema no tiene *middleware*?

Debo aclarar que este sistema, de tal magnitud, no tiene *middleware* (que sería una gloria que tenga porque solventaría muchos problemas arquitectónicos) ya que es un sistema adaptado a un viejo sistema del año 1995 aprox. y otros sistemas más donde la producción era acotada para esas fechas. Hoy en día, se tuvo que actualizar y estamos teniendo problemas de escalabilidad para aumentar la producción.

A entender esto, la *BL* y el *DAL* están en el mismo servidor y, por ende, no me da la posibilidad de distribuir la carga de consulta de datos.

Aclaro que la aplicación tiene el cliente hecho en *WinForms* donde se conectan a los servicios (aplicación de consola).

Comment: Hola, estaría bueno que agregues con que has intentado o algo de tu código ya que tu pregunta es bastante amplia de responder.

Comment: Vos estás interesado en saber cómo implementar algo así a bajo nivel de manera genérica, o en algún caso específico o la utilización de un framework que lo soporte?

Comment: @Zero No tengo código por que sencillamente no se ni por donde empezar. Lo único que tengo es el concepto de que se puede. Y mi pregunta no es amplia pero si puede ser extensa de responder.

Comment: @jachguate Me gustaría saber, cualquiera sea, las dos maneras de implementarlo: especifica o genérica. No se a que referís a bajo nivel. Cuando me decís eso, me imagino de hacer una extensión para SqlServer.

Comment: Lo que podes intentar, es ir a algun sitio de chat de SE, y hablar ahi, quizas te puedan dar consejos para que tengas una pregunta mas especifica.

Comment: Efectivamente la pregunta es muy amplia. Podrias intentar describiendo un poco más el sistema tal vez agregando "quien actualiza la tabla".

Comment: @FabioMaulo, señor "supremo" del NH. Ahora mismo pongo en contexto la pregunta poniéndola en una situación concreta y real.

Comment: viendo que no puedo contestar tu pregunta, por que los chicos la tienen en espera, te recomiendo que te eches una pasadita por ``signalr`` allí encontraras como hacer para que tu servidor SQL Server envie actualizaciones a todos los clientes conectados, esto no es de middleware ni de ``no te recomendaría SSBS`` es simplemente de implementar una tecnología. ahora no se que efectos tenga dado la edad de tu software espero que la tecnología no tenga esa misma edad, pero se puede resolver. lee esto: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-with-sql-server

Comment: Otra posibilidad sería usar las ["Query Notifications"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9x04ed2(v=vs.110).aspx). En CodeProject hay un artículo ["Real Time Notifications using SignalR and SQL Dependency"](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/883702/Real-Time-Notifications-using-SignalR-and-SQL-Depe) explicando como combinarlas con Signalr

Comment: para mi no era necesario todo ese contexto de la pregunta, como estaba antes de ``Actualización`` estaba bien, pero bueno, ni modo tocaba o si no te cerraban la pregunta.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Una solución podría ser usando las "[Query Notifications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/t9x04ed2(v=vs.110).aspx)" que permiten, desde .NET, recibir notificaciones de cambios realizados en los datos de SQL Server. En [este artículo de la MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/62xk7953(v=vs.110).aspx) se puede ver un ejemplo sencillo de como detectar los cambios y recibir los eventos.

También puede ser interesante unir esto con SignalR para que las aplicaciones cliente no sean las que se conectan directamente con SQL Server. En CodeProject hay un artículo "[Real Time Notifications using SignalR and SQL Dependency](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/883702/Real-Time-Notifications-using-SignalR-and-SQL-Depe)" que es muy interesante.

Desconozco si esta solución proporcionará el rendimiento que se necesita o si por el contrario la solución pudieran ser cosas como [SQL Server R Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/mt604845.aspx), un [ServiceBus](https://azure.microsoft.com/es-es/services/service-bus/), ...

Comment: Le diste en el clavo. Es justo lo que necesito para solventar mi necesidad.

Answer (score 7):

Salvo que tu sistema esté fuertemente centralizado en SQL Server (y por lo que comentas no lo parece) no te recomendaría SSBS.

Mi recomendación es que sea tu middleware (allí donde se produzca el origen lógico del evento) el que dispare X proceso (ej. encolar un mensaje).

En el caso particular de una caché, por definición no debería ser actualizada en un entorno distribuido (ej. granja de servidores que cachean localmente consultas a la bbdd).

Si de lo que se trata es de mantener un valor cacheado tan fresco como sea posible, entonces deberías valorar usar esquemas como [Memcached](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memcached) o similares (redis, ...). Básicamente se mantiene una única caché compartida por todos los consumidores de la misma.

Si se trata de una práctica, implementar tu propio memcache puede ser divertido e interesante.

Por otro lado, quizás quieras notificar a los clientes de ciertos cambios, en tal caso existen varias estrategias, la más adecuada en tu caso quizás sería [SignalR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR) pero habría que ver tu caso concreto para ver que forma de escalado es la más adecuada.

En todo caso repito que, salvo motivo puntual, sitúes en la lógica el control sobre el flujo de esa comunicación (bien sea una caché sobre un valor actualizado, un evento que propagas al cliente, etc...).

> Por lo poco que investigué

No estás describiendo ningún sistema de caché (sí de notificación de evento). SSBS puede enviar mensajes a una cola y luego tú desde la aplicación desencolas, así de simple, pero ese esquema es muy rígido y acoplado a la base de datos, necesitas el gestor de colas y además, tu cliente tiene que hacer pull (preguntar explícitamente al gestor de colas si hay nuevos mensajes). Aunque no expones el problema concreto, no parece lo más adecuado (o parece haber mejores alternativas).

Answer (score 6):

Como parte de una solución quizás menos robusta, puedes tener un DDL TRIGGER que inserte en una tabla si han habido cambios en las demás tablas, y luego consultarla desde tu aplicación, de la siguiente manera:

```
CREATE TABLE TRG_TEST
(
ID INT,
NOMBRE_TABLA VARCHAR(50)
)

CREATE TRIGGER TRG_TABLES
ON DATABASE 
AFTER 
    ALTER_TABLE
AS 
    BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @TABLE_NAME SYSNAME

    SELECT 
        @TABLE_NAME = EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]','SYSNAME')

    IF  @TABLE_NAME <> 'TRG_TEST'
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO TRG_TEST VALUES (1,@TABLE_NAME)
    END

END
GO
```

<strike>Seguramente hay una mejor opción para evitar validar el cambio en la tabla que usas para insertar los cambios, algo como SCHEMABINDING o similar.</strike>

Comment: Esta debe ser la mejor opción, usar un trigger que informe de cambio en alguna tabla.